# Linux: Canceling input from /dev/input/event*

Tags: c, linux, input, keyboard

In a program I've been developing, I want to read keyboard strokes independently of whatever window I'm focused on (so, the same program will work whether I'm focused on Firefox or whether I'm playing Minecraft, without having to change focus). So far, using the linux/input.h library and reading from /dev/input/event5 seems to work pretty well.

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
struct input_event ev;
int len = read(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event));
```

However, one feature I would like to add is canceling this input while the program is running, preventing my keystrokes from reaching Firefox or Minecraft or the general OS. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Is this an [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Crippling the OS is a pretty drastic solution.

Comment: Could be. I've looked around for a bit for a solution that lets me capture keyboard input without relying on a dedicated window to be in focus, and just capturing the raw input events seemed to be the easiest. I did try the pynput module but that tended to cause my desktop environment to randomly crash whenever it was installed, so I was rolling my own.

Comment: Ideally, not _all_ keyboard input would be canceled, just input that I identify as useful for my program (pretty much just the letter/number keys, space, and the enter/esc keys that I use to close the program). Also, the program would only run when triggered (at this point, by an Autokey hotkey), so the OS is crippled for a minimum amount of time.

Comment: In Windows API I have used `SetWindowsHookEx()` to look at the keyboard events, but not attempted to interfere with them. Well, not there, I have generated events as though they originated from the keyboard with `SendInput()` but they go to the process that has focus (which can also be manipulated).

Comment: According to [rediculousanddirtyprogramming](https://rediculousanddirtyprogramming.wordpress.com/using-setwindowshookex/), though, SetWindowsHookEx _can_ be used for that purpose if you really want to.
Unfortunately, I'm on Linux (although this could be useful should I want to port my application to Windows).

Comment: The question as asked cannot be answered.  You see, what you need to do, is to *grab* the input device (EVIOCGRAB ioctl), then re-emit any events you do not want to consume using the uinput device.  "un-grabbing" is not "re-emitting", and the latter is what you need to do.  It is common for all sorts of userspace HID daemons that remap stuff like button presses (or e.g. mouth controls) to keypresses or joysticks etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: untested**

- open the character device with mode O_RDWR (read/write)
- grab the device: ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1)
- read events
- if you want to dispatch the event:

  - ungrab device ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 0)
  - write event

Between the ungrab and the write, other events could occur, which will not filtered and dispatched to all connected file handles. I don't know if it is possible to write first and ungrab afterwards (or even write at all, check the return value of `write`).

**Hint**: You could also modify [libevdev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/libevdev/doc/latest/).

Comment: This actually works pretty well. Two things to keep in mind, though:

1. Pausing the program for a second before grabbing is essential (`sleep(1);`). Otherwise, whatever keystroke was used to trigger the program (i.e. the enter key in a terminal environment) won't ever have its "key-up" call sent to the OS, resulting in an endless stream of repeating strokes.

2. We can use the return code of the ioctl call to ensure that only one instance of the program is running at a time, exiting if it is below 0. Combined with the above, it should prevent an infinite number of processes generating.