# Linux: Set keyboard focus to background process

Tags: python, c, linux, keyboard

I'm trying to build an application that lets me capture user input to build a search query that I pass to another application, with the goal of triggering the second application without the window focus ever leaving whatever the user is currently doing.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is this:

1. User is playing a full-screen game like Minecraft or something
2. User uses a keyboard shortcut to trigger my background application (at the moment, accomplished via the Autokey utility).
3. User types in a query. All of this input is sent to the background application instead of Minecraft, even though Minecraft has window focus the entire time and can still react to mouse input and the like. OS-level shortcuts like Alt+Tab still work. To ensure that the user knows what is going on, audio feedback will be played when my background application is active.
4. User exits the program with either the Esc key or the Enter key. If Enter is pressed, the text entered via the keyboard is sent to a separate program for further processing and action. Either way, the background application releases the keyboard, and further keystrokes will go to Minecraft.

What I still need to figure out is how to redirect the keyboard input without generating a new window (and thus causing fullscreen applications to lose focus). So far, I've had two ideas. My first one, the pynput module, worked rather well, but it caused by desktop environment to crash whenever it was installed, making that an unstable solution. I've also looked into directly capturing input from the /dev/input/event* streams, but that only seems to let me monitor input, not capture it like a regular window would.

Comment: Wouldn't any existing keylogger do most of the work you described ?

Comment: I actually did to that by monitoring /dev/input/event*, and it works pretty well. The only issue is that key events still reach the main window, which isn't what I wanted (typing in "dreams" can easily cause me to wander off a cliff before opening up my inventory). I did ask about [canceling input from /dev/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713392/linux-canceling-input-from-dev-input-event), but the general consensus appears to be that I'm going about the problem the wrong way, so I'm fishing for an alternative solution.